# Reorganization Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a date frame of the following kind:

```
|user|product|quantity|
|1   |   1   |   4    | 
|1   |   1   |   3    |
|1   |   2   |   1    |
|2   |   1   |   5    |
|2   |   1   |   8    |
|2   |   5   |   7    |
 ...    ...      ...
```

I want to get the date frame of the next kind:

```
|user|product_1|product_2|...|product_5|...|product_n|
|1   |   7     |    1    |...|   0     |...|    0    | 
|2   |   13    |    0    |...|   7     |...|   ...   |
 ...     ...       ...    ...   ...     ...    ...
```

How can it be done quickly and efficiently on a very large amount of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with `aggfunc="sum"` to reshape the dataframe from long format to a wide one. Post that, format the column names with the help of `add_prefix` option.

```
d = df.pivot_table(index='user', columns='product', 
                   values='quantity', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
d.add_prefix("product_").rename_axis([None], axis=1)
```

[image]

---

It's equivalent `groupby` syntax would be computing the sum across the grouped columns and then unstacking the dataframe. Followed by similar operations as per the afore-mentioned approach.

```
d1 = df.groupby(['user', 'product'])['quantity'].sum()
d1.unstack(fill_value=0).add_prefix("product_").rename_axis([None], axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me

Answer (score 1):

Try [`pd.DataFrame.unstack()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html). That does exactly what you want.

Update: I wanted to extend this answer, but due to a meeting too late now, the other answer is good. But, by now (assuming, you only have **one number per user-product**, so no need for groupby):

```
df = df.set_index(['user', 'product'])
df = df.unstack(-1).fillna(0)  # only if you want to fill the NaNs
```

Comment: `set_index/unstack` alone would not work here as the OP wants to perform a grouped sum. Although they haven't mentioned this in their post, from the looks of the resulting `DF`, it's pretty much clear they're after that.

Comment: Yes, I also needed the amount-sum

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't had the the look on the original dataframe. Therefore, Nickils answer is better for the case.